# How to Set a Range Based on a User Selected cell reference in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently running a code where the user selects a cell reference (which is the column heading name) and the code creates a dataset from that selection. The current code creates the data by running a find command on the selected heading string. This has worked really well but it is problematic if the heading appears twice in the same row. What I want to do instead is replace the find string with an offset from the selected row but am having trouble.

The original code, using a find string was:

```
Sub test()

Dim ar1 As Variant
Dim str1 As String
Dim ar2 As Variant
Dim Path As String
Dim j As Long 'counter
Dim output As String

Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path

ar1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C6:C222").Value

str1 = Application.InputBox("Select data heading from row 6", _
        "Obtain String", Type:=2)

ar2 = Range(Range("E6:IP6").Find(str1),Range("E6:IP6").Find(str1).End(xlDown))


For j = 1 To UBound(ar1, 1)
  output = output & ar1(j, 1) & "," & ar2(j, 1) & vbNewLine
Next

Open Path & "\text_data.txt" For Output As #1
Print #1, output
Close
End Sub
```

My new code attempt is as follows, however I keep getting a Run time error '1004 - Application defined or object-defined error.L when the code gets to the line where I set the ar2 array

```
ar2 = Range(rng1.Offset(0, 0), rng1.Offset(216, 0))


Sub test()

Dim ar1 As Variant
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim ar2 As Variant
Dim Path As String
Dim j As Long 'counter
Dim output As String

Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path

ar1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C6:C222").Value

set rng1 = Application.InputBox("Select data heading from row 6", _
        "Obtain String", Type:=8)

ar2 = Range(rng1.Offset(0, 0), rng1.Offset(216, 0))

For j = 1 To UBound(ar1, 1)
  output = output & ar1(j, 1) & "," & ar2(j, 1) & vbNewLine
Next

Open Path & "\text_data.txt" For Output As #1
Print #1, output
Close
End Sub
```

Any help is gratefully appreciated

Comment: **On which line ??**

Comment: Apologies, on the line where i define the array ar2

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the problem is pasted below. In the end what I did was to resize the range that is selected by the user in the input box command and offset it by the number of required rows that the data starts below the heading. This works OK for me because my data is always of a certain fixed length below the selected heading.

The reference for offseting ranges came from [Microsoft Support Page on Selecting Range References in VBA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/291308)

```
Sub test()

Dim ar1 As Variant
Dim ar2 As Variant
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim Path As String
Dim j As Long
Dim output As String

Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path

ar1 = Worksheets("Find Friends").Range("C6:C222").Value

Set rng1 = Application.InputBox("Select data heading from row 5", _
            "Select Indicator", Type:=8)

ar2 = rng1.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng1.Rows.Count + 215, rng1.Columns.Count)

For j = 1 To UBound(ar1, 1)
    output = output & ar1(j, 1) & "," & ar2(j, 1) & vbNewLine
Next

Open Path & "\text_data.txt" For Output As #1
Print #1, output
Close

End Sub
```